# Show popup window if a variable in database is set to 1

Tags: php, html

I would like to have a popup windows on screen if a variable is set to 1, Im using PHP to load the page. So lets say I have the variable $Flag. on page load if the variable is 1 show the popup until the user click close. if $flag is set to 0 load the page as normal.
Im able to create a modal for the pop up and get the variable from the database, but how can i put those 2 together?

PHP Code:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['CurrentUser'])) {
    $AppID=$_SESSION['CurrentUser'];

    $ApplicantDetailsSQL=mysql_query("SELECT Accepted FROM Applicant WHERE AppID = '$AppID'");
    $ApplicantDetails = mysql_fetch_assoc($ApplicantDetailsSQL);
    if ($ApplicantDetails['Accepted'] == '1') {
        //Show modal
    }

}
```

HTML Code:

```
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

The HTML Modal is copy/paste from W3School.

Comment: do an `if/else`

Comment: On the W3CSchool example a modal requires a button to popup. I can do that, what I cant figure out is to make it popup depended on the varriable.how to trigger the model through PHP?

Comment: replace/remove the condition for the button. You really should post relevant code and add relevant tags

Comment: I have updated the question with my code.Thanks for your replies

Comment: So, first start by getting the modal to be displayed when your page loads.  Then, as Fred-ii- said, is an if/else to only display that content when your `$flag=1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution PHP:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['CurrentUser'])) {
    $AppID=$_SESSION['CurrentUser'];

    $ApplicantDetailsSQL=mysql_query("SELECT Accepted FROM Applicant WHERE AppID = '$AppID'");
    $ApplicantDetails = mysql_fetch_assoc($ApplicantDetailsSQL);
    if ($ApplicantDetails['Accepted'] == '1') {
        $modal = true;
    }
    else{
        $modal = false;
    }

}
```

HTML:

```
  <?php if($modal)
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'> $(window).load(function(){ $('#myModal').modal('show'); }); </script>";
      ?>

    </div> <!-- /container -->

     <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">You are already a student</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>You have already been accepted to one of our courses. This website is for application puproses only.</p>
              <p>Since you are already a student, most of the functionality has been disabled for your account. Please login to the university's student portal for further.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: I've always admired people who solve problems by themselves. I honestly don't know why your answer was downvoted;  I originally gave it an upvote for solving it on your own. Whoever did downvote it, IMHO wasn't very nice.

Comment: Voting sometimes is used as a weapon and kill the community. In this community, there are professionals, hobbies and completely newbies to coding. By downvoting a question/answer I agree you are helping the context to be free of useless questions but at the same time you are discouraging someone to ask again, or even leave the sport for real, cause they making him fill but about his low knowledge on coding. Im not trying to be the bad guy, im just giving food for thought here.. Thanks everyone for your help though.